# What does "淦" mean?

Tags: meaning

I used Google translate but it shows "Gan", which cannot be its true meaning (it's just the pronunciation). Is that the liquid state of gold? But I think it should be a verb.

Comment: [淦 gàn](http://www.zdic.net/z/1d/xs/6DE6.htm)

Comment: big wave triggered by ships. try to search www.zdic.net for it.

Comment: Google translate somehow gave you "correct" translation, since this word mostly used as place name.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, it means “fuck.” Beacuse its pronunciation is just the same as “干,” which is a verb, means "do something," but some people use it to insult other people, in this case it means fuck...

Answer (score 1):

[淦 - wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B7%A6)

> Han character
>
> 淦 (radical 85 水+8, 11 strokes, cangjie input 水金 (EC), four-corner 38119, composition ⿰氵金)
>
> - river in Jiangxi province
> - water leaking into a boat
>
> References
>
> KangXi: page 630, character 25
>      Dai Kanwa Jiten: character 17667
>      Dae Jaweon: page 1033, character 5
>      Hanyu Da Zidian: volume 3, page 1653, character 3
>      Unihan data for U+6DE6

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you mean, as you thought it should be a verb, but I'm not sure if it's possible to explain such a rude slang here.

The true verb which has the same pronunciation as `淦`, is a verb involved with sexual harassment or verbal violence. That's all I can tell. Hope you're unintentional.

Edit: Note: The usage is mostly dominant in Taiwan and rarely in other Chinese speaking areas.